# How does algorithmic trading actually work?

Tags: algorithmic-trading

https://zorro-project.com/code.php

So I'm re-posting an example trading algorithm posted on a certain website.

The functions and loops and all are obvious but there are some objects (I guess it's C so you should call them methods or other term but bear with me) like...

```
MovingAverages=series(SMA(seriesC(),300));
crossOver(seriesC(), MovingAverages))
crossUnder(SeriesC(), MovingAverages))
```

the origins of which are not specified. My question is:

Apart from the data importation process, the sell/buy orders need to be made automatically by the code; but how does the code actually access the order process? Do the MovingAverages and crossOver and other elements contain pre-determined ways to press the sell/buy buttons? How is this part actually automated?

Thank you.

I'm a newbie to this.